# nginx wont start after reboot Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django

I'm getting this error:

nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "app_server" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django.save:1

this is my config file:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
cd  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

sudo rm -r django.save

sudo service nginx restart

 * Restarting nginx nginx                                                [ OK ]
```

Comment: I know what happened. You backed up your config in the .save file. Nginx does not care what your file is called, it just executes every file in that folder. So when it came across second config file configuring the same port, it complained.

Comment: In my case, the cause was another nginx config file that declared upstream app_server { ... }.  (We all copied from the same examples to start.)  The solution was to rename "app_server" to something else.